# Undo Redo In Textarea possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

I was wondering if there's a way of having undo redo in html form textarea?  Is there a way this could be implemented without using a wysiwyg editor and using jquery and keyboard shortcuts ctrl+y ctrl + z?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most browsers these days have undo/redo (ctrl-z, ctrl-y) for text areas built in already.  Firefox has, as does Safari and Chrome, and I'm fairly sure even IE supports it.  Can't say if Opera has support but I'd be surprised if it doesn't

Comment: Opera does (typing this on opera using CTRL-Z CTRL-Y as we speak)